# Why Julia produces #undef keys in Dictionary?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, julia

I have made a dictionary of histograms on Julia, with a lot of entries. The keys are 4 element integer arrays, as a simple call to the object returns:

```
In[88] Histogramas
Out[88] Dict{Array{Int64,N},Array{T,N}} with 36540 entries:
  [56,8,39,55]  => [0,2,4,7,19,44,61,76,124,116  …  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  [64,20,48,55] => [284,368,202,106,35,3,2,0,0,0  …  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  [54,9,50,54]  => [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2  …  1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  [37,26,45,61] => [0,6,11,35,47,86,113,133,136,139  …  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  [37,15,51,50] => [673,272,48,5,2,0,0,0,0,0  …  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  [35,22,53,45] => [331,370,201,69,25,4,0,0,0,0  …  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  [37,25,56,40] => [460,382,127,27,3,0,1,0,0,0  …  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
....
```

But if i call `Histogramas.keys` then I get this very weird output:

```
Out[90] : 65536-element Array{Array{Int64,N},1}:
 #undef          
 #undef          
    [56,8,39,55] 
 #undef          
    [64,20,48,55]
    [54,9,50,54] 
 #undef          
    [37,26,45,61]
    [37,15,51,50]
...
```

So I got almost twice keys as there are entries of the dictionary, and most of the extra ones are `#undef`, which, by the way, I also do not know what that means. ¿Undefined in what sense?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is not the right way to get a `Dict`'s keys – you're accidentally accessing the private internal fields of the `Dict` object. The correct way to access a `Dict`'s keys is to call the `keys` function on the `Dict` object:

```
julia> d = Dict(:foo => 1.2, :bar => 2.3, :baz => 3.4)
Dict{Symbol,Float64} with 3 entries:
  :bar => 2.3
  :baz => 3.4
  :foo => 1.2

julia> keys(d)
Base.KeyIterator for a Dict{Symbol,Float64} with 3 entries. Keys:
  :bar
  :baz
  :foo
```

The output `#undef` when displaying an array indicates an uninitialized entry in the array. This is similar to a `null` value in C, C++ or Java, but unlike `null`, in Julia `#undef` is non-first-class: it is not a value that you can use or pass around; any use of an undefined field or array slot is an immediate exception.

In general, Julia is not a "dot oriented language": whereas in Python or Java you might expect to do `obj.frob` to access `obj`'s `frob` or do `obj.frizzle()` to frizzle `obj`, in Julia that is unlikely to be the right thing to do. You would most likely do `frob(obj)` and `frizzle(obj)` instead.

Comment: And the dot notation, what is its use in Julia then? Many thanks, Stefan, you are always answering my questions!

Comment: The dot notation is only for literal field access. There's been discussion of allowing it to be overloaded but that has not yet happened.